# How To Send All Requests To A CGI Script Without It Appearing In The URL From The .Htaccess File?

Tags: python, .htaccess, hosting, cgi, web-hosting

I am trying to send all the requests to my web server to a `.cgi` script without it appearing in the url (The cgi script is running Python Flask)
For example, if you go to this url:
`https://example.com/page/page2`
It would send the request to `main.cgi` with the path `/page/page2`, however `/main.cgi` wouldn't appear in the url. Also, I would like it so the user can *not* access any of the static files by going to their url. 
So far, I have tried the following .htaccess files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main.cgi/$1 [L]
```

Sadly, this allows the user to access static files by going to their url. For example, the url `example.com/static/image.jpg` would return the image, not whatever is returned from the cgi script.

I have also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/main.cgi
RewriteRule .*/main.cgi
```

However, this removes the url path. For example, this url: `example.com/hello` would just be redirected to `example.com`.

How can I make the htaccess send requests to a cgi script without it appearing in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main.cgi/$1 [L]
> ```

This rewrites all requests that do not map to real files (which includes directories) to `/main.cgi`, passing the requested URL-path as path-info to your script (which your CGI script is presumably expecting). I'm assuming this is working in that regard?

To rewrite *everything* then you would need to remove the `RewriteCond` directive (as you did later), but you do need to prevent internal requests for `/main.cgi` being internally rewritten, which would otherwise create a rewrite-loop (500 error response).

For example:

```
RewriteRule !^main\.cgi main.cgi%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This rewrites all requests that are not already for `/main.cgi` to `/main.cgi/<url>`.

The `!` prefix operator on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* negates the regex - to the rule is successful when the regex does not match. There is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* when used in `.htaccess`. The slash prefix on the *substitution* string is not required here. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the root-relative URL-path (including the slash prefix), so this does not need to be captured using the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/main.cgi
> RewriteRule .*/main.cgi
> ```
>
> However, this removes the url path. For example, this url: example.com/hello would just be redirected to example.com.

These directives are not actually valid (the `RewriteRule` is missing a 2nd argument), so can't actually be doing anything? However, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `.*/main.cgi` won't match the URL you stated earlier, so again, I can't see that this would be doing anything. (?)